# Why child div hover does not working due to z-index?

Tags: html, css

I added `position:relative` and `z-index:-10` on `#content` in media query `767` pixel for resolving some issues on small screens and `#content` has a lot of dynamically generated child products. But due to added styles on `#content` child hover does not working, also products does not clickable.

### HTML

```
<div id="content" >
    <div id="products" class="row list-group">
        <div class="child-product">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#content{
position:relative;
z-index:-10
}
```

I tried to `overflow` types for solving this issue, but does not working. Can any one guide me how can i fix this issue.

Comment: You cannot hover over the below layers.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal so is there possible that i fix this issue with out removing the `#content` `z-index` ?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal ok, so i think i should use `z-index` on each child product instead of `#content` may be in this way both issues will be resolved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position something in front of something else in CSS there are a few ways to do it.

First of all, regular elements are positioned in front of previous siblings:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

In this case, 'two' is positioned ABOVE 'one', however without additional styles these divs wouldn't intersect so you can't really tell.

If we were to change the z-indices on either element, we wouldn't really be rearranging them, as z-index values have no effect on `position: initial` elements. Granting any of the elements `position: relative` or `absolute`, will place them above their siblings.

Two elements with `position: absolute` for instance, can then be modified with z-index, however don't use a negative z-index.

Answer (score 2):

don't put a parent container value in negative (z-index: -10) you can give it a minimum value in Positive like(z-index:1) and so on according to you requirement and everything will work fine but don't put negative value

```
  #content{
   position:relative;
   z-index:1
}
```

Comment: Due to `z-index:1` there are some layout issue facing on mobile screen